# Bash script ignore other part of if, even when it is supposed to be executed

Tags: bash

I have a following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
public_ip=$(curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//')
#echo "$public_ip"
declare -a FILELIST
for existing_user in $(ls /home/); do
        #echo "$existing_user"
        FILELIST[${#FILELIST[@]}+1]=$(echo "$existing_user")
done

declare -a FILELIST_WITH_VALID_USERS
echo "Start execution of user-check.sh"
while read -r line; do
  # Split the line into a name and a list of variables
  IFS=',' read -r server_ip package_type users <<< "$line"
  echo "$server_ip $package_type $users"
  if [[ $public_ip == $server_ip ]]; then
         IFS=',' read -r -a users_array <<< "$users"
         for user in "${users_array[@]}"; do
                [[ ${FILELIST[*]} =~ "$user" ]] && echo  "$user is valid and should be present in server $server_ip" ||  echo "$user should be deleted and is not supposed to be present in server $server_ip"
         done

  fi
done < server.info
```

It is main goal to get existing users into array from /home and to get users from file server.info and then to notify if user is present in /home but not is present in server.info

Server.info looks like this(format: server_ip, package_type, array of users):

```
104.248.245.89,rpm,auditor,igor.test,ivan.test,michael.test,vova.test,testbot
```

When I run it here is output:

```
Start execution of user-check.sh
104.248.245.89 rpm auditor,igor.test,ivan.test,michael.test,vova.test,testbot
auditor is valid and should be present in server 104.248.245.89
igor.test is valid and should be present in server 104.248.245.89
ivan.test is valid and should be present in server 104.248.245.89
michael.test is valid and should be present in server 104.248.245.89
vova.test is valid and should be present in server 104.248.245.89
testbot is valid and should be present in server 104.248.245.89
```

However in my ls /home I also have user ruslan.test and bash script should output that this user is invalid as it is not present in /home

Comment: Your last sentence is conflicting.  First, you say ruslan.test in in list provided by 'ls /home' ... then you end by saying "not present in /home" !!! That makes no sense.  Please make the correction by replacing either reference with the server.info file.

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless use of `ls`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls); you want  `for dir in /home/*; do existing_user=${dir#/home/}` etc; and a useless `echo`; simply `FILELIST+=($existing_user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *problem* with the logic of your script is that you are using the list containing ONLY known VALID users (**server.info**) as the list for the loop performing the check.

You should be using the list of **candidates** that need to be evaluated (**home_users.list**) for that!  I made that change for the first testing loop.

I also modified the logic and report of the original loop to report which "authorized" users were not yet created on the remote host.

A test version of your script showing this is as follows.  I have taken the liberty to offer some suggestions on formatting the output, to make things stand out during visual scan and easier to parse for a subsequent "cleanup batch".

```
#!/bin/bash

redON="\e[91;1m"
redOFF="\e[0m"
orangeON="\e[33;1m"                                                                                       
orangeOFF="\e[0m"

cat >server.info <<EnDoFiNpUt
104.248.245.89,rpm,auditor,igor.test,ivan.test,michael.test,vova.test,newbot,testbot
EnDoFiNpUt

cat >home_users.list <<EnDoFiNpUt
auditor
igor.test
ivan.test
michael.test
ruslan.test
vova.test
testbot
EnDoFiNpUt

declare -a FILELIST
i=0
#for existing_user in $(ls /home/)
for existing_user in $(cat home_users.list)
do  #echo "$existing_user"
        FILELIST[${i}]=$(echo "$existing_user")
    i=$((i+=1))
    #echo "${i} => ${existing_user}"
done

public_ip=$(curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//')
#echo "$public_ip"
public_ip=104.248.245.89

#declare -a FILELIST    # FILELIST_WITH_VALID_USERS

echo "Running 'user-check.sh' ..."
while read -r line
do
  # Split the line into a name and a list of variables
  IFS=',' read -r server_ip package_type users <<< "${line}"
  printf "[${server_ip}] ${package_type} ${users}\n"

  if [[ ${public_ip} == ${server_ip} ]]
  then
         IFS=',' read -r -a users_array <<< "${users}"

         for user in "${FILELIST[@]}"
         do
            if [[ ${users_array[*]} =~ "${user}" ]]
            then
                #echo "${user} is valid and should be present in server ${server_ip}"
                printf "[${server_ip}] Valid and confirmed - ${user}\n"
            else
                #echo "${user} should be deleted and is not supposed to be present in server ${server_ip}"
                printf "[${redON}PURGE${redOFF}] ${user} @ ${server_ip} for ${package_type}\n"
            fi
         done
         for user in "${users_array[@]}"
         do
            if [[ ! ${FILELIST[*]} =~ "${user}" ]]
            then
                printf "[${orangeON}MISSING${orangeOFF}] ${user} @ ${server_ip} for ${package_type}\n"
            fi
         done

  fi
done < server.info
```

The session output is as follows:

```
ericthered:/0__WORK$ ./test_95.sh
Running 'user-check.sh' ...
[104.248.245.89] rpm auditor,igor.test,ivan.test,michael.test,vova.test,newbot,testbot
[104.248.245.89] Valid and confirmed - auditor
[104.248.245.89] Valid and confirmed - igor.test
[104.248.245.89] Valid and confirmed - ivan.test
[104.248.245.89] Valid and confirmed - michael.test
[PURGE] ruslan.test @ 104.248.245.89 for rpm
[104.248.245.89] Valid and confirmed - vova.test
[104.248.245.89] Valid and confirmed - testbot
[MISSING] newbot @ 104.248.245.89 for rpm
ericthered:/0__WORK$
```

or graphically,

[image]